# Returning extra column with SELECT (max)T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

First post so please be nice. [SQL Server 2014]

I'm currently running a select against a table which looks like the below

```
select 
ExerciseCultures.Name,
max (convert (decimal (10,2), cast(weight as float))) as [Max Weight (KG)]
from workoutsessions
        join ExerciseCultures on workoutsessions.ExerciseID 
        = ExerciseCultures.ExerciseID
group by ExerciseCultures.Name
```

Which returns 31 rows, one for each exerciseID showing the highest 'weight' value for each one.

What I need is an additional column which also shows the date for each of these rows. The date column is already a column in the workoutsessions table alongside each row.

I've tried adding this date column, using the below:

```
select 
ExerciseCultures.Name,
max (convert (decimal (10,2), cast(weight as float))) as [Max Weight (KG)],
workoutsessions.date
from workoutsessions
        join ExerciseCultures on workoutsessions.ExerciseID 
        = ExerciseCultures.ExerciseID
group by ExerciseCultures.Name,
    workoutsessions.date
```

But this then returns 286 rows -- all of the rows in the parent table. What I need is the original query results with just their respective date from the workoutsessions table.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks

Comment: what is the datatype of weight?, why are you first converting it to float and then to decimal?

Comment: Well done for asking a reasonable first question, not many do!

Comment: @Lamak Weight is varchar, I was having difficulty converting it directly decimal and this was a recommended solution.

Comment: @DanielAndré Yes, the ID appears multiple times in the sessions table with various dates.

Comment: @Adam yes, but can the same ID have more then one date? cause if it can, and if i'm undertanding it correctly you have multiple dates to group with ExerciseCultures.Name, and thats why you are having so many rows

Comment: @DanielAndré Hi Daniel, yes it can. Is there a way I can return the main query and then the date for those returned rows?

Comment: @Adam thats what you are already getting. You must have something like this: row 1 = ID1->date1; row 2 = ID1->date2 (....); row n = ID2->date3 ... but you want something like: ID1->date1,date2; ID2->date3 is that correct? Since you are grouping by both ID and Date you get the results paired by unique IDs and Dates, so you end up getting multiple rows with the same ID

Comment: @DanielAndré Hi Daniel. What I'd like is to find the MAX value against ID1 and return the DATE for that row. So say I had two rows: (ID1, 12, 01/01/2014) and (ID1, 10, 15/01/2014) it would return the first row  as the 12 is the max value for that ID. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Adam yes thank you, ill post my awnser shortly

Comment: Which date do you want in the case that `[Max Weight (KG)]` exists in more than one row with same `excerciseCultures.name`.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Hi Sharon, very good point. Didn't even think about that as I'm not sure it occurs in my data set. I would have it return the earlier date if this is the case. Many thanks.

Comment: Then add `date desc` to the order criteria of @Lamak's or @EarlOfEnnui's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  e.Name,
            CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),CAST(weight AS FLOAT))) [Max Weight (KG)],
            w.[date],
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY e.name 
                                    ORDER BY CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),CAST(weight AS FLOAT))) DESC)
    FROM workoutsessions w
    INNER JOIN ExerciseCultures e
        ON w.ExerciseID = e.ExerciseID
)
SELECT name, [Max Weight (KG)], [date]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.NAME, 
       A.[max weight (kg)], 
       B.date 
FROM   (SELECT exercisecultures.NAME, 
               Max (CONVERT (DECIMAL (10, 2), Cast(weight AS FLOAT))) AS [Max Weight (KG)] 
        FROM   workoutsessions 
               JOIN exercisecultures 
                 ON workoutsessions.exerciseid = exercisecultures.exerciseid 
        GROUP  BY exercisecultures.NAME) A 
        JOIN workoutsessions B 
          ON a.NAME = b.NAME 
             AND CONVERT (DECIMAL (10, 2), Cast(B.weight AS FLOAT)) = 
                 A.[max weight (kg)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT 
    ExerciseCultures.Name,
    ws.[weight],
    ws.[date]
FROM ExerciseCultures
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [weight], [date] 
                 FROM workoutsessions
                 WHERE ExerciseCultures.ExerciseID = ExerciseID
                 ORDER BY [weight] desc) ws
```

Comment: Need to convert the weight to numeric first. Ordering of strings holding numbers and the numbers themselves very different.

Comment: Hi Earl, many thanks. I've not used cross apply before so will look into that more, but this seems to have done the trick with a little tweaking to convert the weight column. Although this has highlighted that converting from char to decimal is very messy -- going to fix the column input and change it to a better suited datatype. Many thanks.